# Interdependent conflicting packages in CentOS 6.5

Tags: centos, package-management, upgrade

I've been using **CentOS 6.5** as my OS for quite a while. Usually I don't have many problems with Linux installations, but as they new **CentOS 6.6** was released I found myself in a bit of a problem. There were hundred of updates to be done, but only one turned out to be problematic. If I input the command
`yum update` I get

```
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package scl-utils.i686 0:20120927-8.el6 will be updated
---> Package scl-utils.i686 0:20120927-23.el6_6 will be an update
---> Package xcb-util.i686 0:0.3.6-1.el6 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libxcb-icccm.so.1 for package: qt5-qtbase-gui-5.3.2-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libxcb-image.so.0 for package: qt5-qtbase-gui-5.3.2-1.el6.i686
--> Processing Dependency: libxcb-keysyms.so.1 for package: qt5-qtbase-gui-5.3.2-1.el6.i686
---> Package xcb-util.i686 0:0.3.6-5.el6 will be an update
--> Running transaction check
---> Package xcb-util.i686 0:0.3.6-1.el6 will be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libxcb-icccm.so.1 for package: qt5-qtbase-gui-5.3.2-1.el6.i686
---> Package xcb-util-image.i686 0:0.3.9-4.el6 will be installed
---> Package xcb-util-keysyms.i686 0:0.3.9-5.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: qt5-qtbase-gui-5.3.2-1.el6.i686 (@epel)
       Requires: libxcb-icccm.so.1
       Removing: xcb-util-0.3.6-1.el6.i686 (@anaconda-CentOS-201311271240.i386/6.5)
           libxcb-icccm.so.1
       Updated By: xcb-util-0.3.6-5.el6.i686 (base)
           Not found
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Now, I know that often these sort of conflicts come from updates from different repos, but this is my current repo list

1. adobe-linux-i386       Adobe Systems Incorporated
2. base                   CentOS-6 - Base
3. epel                   Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 6 - i386
4. extras                 CentOS-6 - Extras
5. google-chrome          google-chrome
6. spideroak-stable       SpiderOak Stable Distribution
7. updates                CentOS-6 - Updates
   And the weird thing is that it seems that the conflicting packages not only come from the same repository, but are actually dependencies!
   `xcb-util` in fact asks me to install `xcb-util-image` and `xcb-util-keysyms` as dependencies..and then conflicts with them! The current version of `xcb-util` does not have these other two dependencies installed, and says that `Source RPM: xcb-util-0.3.6-1.el6.sr`.
   This is a bit weird. Has anyone met this problem?
   Many thanks, and I hope I provided enough information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is qt5 from epel, I removed it and upgrade without problem. There is already fixed qt5 in epel-testing: https://admin.fedoraproject.org/updates/FEDORA-EPEL-2014-3484/qt5-qtbase-5.3.2-3.el6

Comment: This seemed to have worked very well. I'll wait until qt5 comes out of testing before re-installing it.

Answer (score -1):

Enable only by default centos repo and disable other repo then run the commands

1. `yum clean all`
2. `yum update all`